# How to fill the Facebook embedded video's width in its container with ReactPlayer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, facebook, next.js, react-player

I want to add an embedded video to my NextJS app. I am using ReactPlayer but it seems that Facebook does not support the width="100%", because with youtube it works well but when I use a Facebook video, it's always snaps back on 500px. Anyone knows what is up.

Even if I go into de DOM and change the width 500px to width: 100% in the inspector it snaps back to 500px.
[image]

```
<ReactPlayer
            ref={videoRef}
            controls={true}
            width="100%"
            height="100%"
            url="https://www.facebook.com/PACMANCOMMUNITY/videos/922852058607774/"
            playing={playing}
            muted={muted}
            onDuration={durationHandler}
            onProgress={progressHandler}
            config={{
              youtube: {
                playerVars: { showinfo: 1 },
              },
            }}
          />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was that I conditionally rendered the reactplayer, if I didn't conditionally render it took its full width.